# How to check which port is block by proxy server

Tags: proxy

I'm using Saudi Arabia proxy server 212.93.193.88:443
I can't the pop3 mail with default port 25 & 110, pop3s 995 & 465
I still wanna know how can i check which port is block by proxy server.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, are you sure that you need to connect to your mail servers through the proxy? A http proxy is typically only meant for web connections.

If you do, you need to make sure that your email applications are actually establishing their connections through the proxy. By default, most email applications will **not** connect via a http proxy server. You can do this by monitoring your network connections using whatever tools are present on your OS. At the minimum, you should have `netstat` that can be used as a crude monitor.

Secondly, if your email applications are **really** using the connection through the http proxy, it is possible that the proxy server has been configured to only allow connections to port 80 and 443. You can test this by telnet into the proxy (possibly over SSL) and issuing a `CONNECT` command to see if it can connect to non port 80/443 servers.